# RTL semanticContentAttribute .playback on iOS 10 not working

Tags: ios, iphone, internationalization, ios9, ios10

I set audio cell to semanticContentAttribute to .playback but the cell still flip in Arabic language on iOS 10. It works on iOS 9. does anyone has an idea of whats wrong?

**iOS 10**
[image]

**iOS 9**
[image]

I also noticed that status bar didn't flip on iOS 9

Comment: On which object are you setting the `semanticContentAttribute`?

Comment: @wakachamo on cell contentView

Comment: Could you file a bug at bugreport.apple.com?

Comment: @wakachamo okay I will fil a bug. But is there any workaround.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Auto Layout? You can change the constraint types to be 'Left' and 'Right' instead of 'Leading' and 'Trailing'